# How to convert sql union to codeigniter way

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, search, union

How to do UNION query with PHP CodeIgniter framework's i am getting error when i execute this query

```
Every derived table must have its own alias
```

Model

```
function search_blog($title){
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT id,section,title,img,year,lastupdateon AS ondate,'moves' AS dept,STATUS FROM movies
                UNION
                SELECT ID,section,Title,img,year,lastupdateon AS ondate,'kid' AS dept,STATUS FROM kids
                UNION
                SELECT ID,views,Title,img,version AS year,ondate,'software' AS dept,STATUS FROM soft
                UNION
                SELECT ID,section,Title,img,'PC Game' AS year,ondate,'game' AS dept,STATUS FROM games
                UNION
                SELECT ID,season,Title,img,type AS year,lastupdatedon AS ondate,'tvshow' AS dept,STATUS FROM tvshows
                )");
        $this->db->like('Title', $title , 'after');
        $this->db->order_by('ondate', 'DESC');
        $this->db->limit(10);
        return $this->db->get($query)->result();
    }
```

how to change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this simply by adding query for each table and join them using union like this

```
$this->db->select('ID,section,title,img,year,lastupdateon AS ondate,`moves` AS dept,STATUS');
$this->db->from('movies');
$query1 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

$this->db->select('ID,section,title,img,year,lastupdateon AS ondate,`kid` AS dept,STATUS');
$this->db->from('kids');
$query2 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

$this->db->select('ID,views,title,img,version AS year,ondate,`software` AS dept,STATUS');
$this->db->from('soft');
$query3 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();


$this->db->select('ID,section,title,img,'PC Game' AS year,ondate,`game` AS dept,STATUS');
$this->db->from('games');
$query4 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

$this->db->select('ID,season,title,img,type AS year,lastupdatedon AS ondate,`tvshow` AS dept,STATUS');
$this->db->from('tvshows');
$query5 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

$this->db->like('title', $title , 'after');
$this->db->order_by('ondate', 'DESC');
$this->db->limit(10);


$query = $this->db->query($query1 . ' UNION ' . $query2. ' UNION ' . $query3. ' UNION ' . $query4. ' UNION ' . $query5);

return $this->db->get($query)->result();
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205742/discussion-on-answer-by-amit-sharma-how-to-convert-sql-union-to-codeigniter-way).

Comment: Please have a look. I think its fixed

Comment: Its getting results from the last posting dates but not from the search term

Comment: Working Perfectly now Thanks